# how to hide android keyboard in onPostExecute() method of async task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am fetching records from database in android using async task .
I have edittext andone search button when user enters any text and clicks search button it is fetching records from db .but after fetching records from db keyboard is still present on the screen .
i want to hide it in onPostExecute() and it should reopen when user again tries to enter text in edittext .

Answer (score 3):

Try below code on onPostExecute() method:-

```
public static void hideKeypad(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity
                    .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

above method works fine in my all application.

Comment: what u think will it reopen when user will try to type in edittext